# Need assistance in finding out why option doesnt pop up in drop down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drop-down-menu

I'm writing this C# code in which I created a drop-down box, and when I attach my code to the on value change it would show the option I wanna select. Idk if I did something wrong or what but could someone help me out with that.
changeshape is was don't see in the dropdown box.

[image: This is where i dont see the option appear]

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ClickManager : MonoBehaviour

{
    private int shape = 0;
    private GameObject primitive;
    
private float red = 1f, green = 1f, blue = 1f;
    
public Text mousePosition;

    private float distance = 5f, distanceChange;

    private Vector3 clickPosition;
    private bool timeDestroy = true;
    private float size = 0.5f;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)|| Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit))
            {
                Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)|| Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            clickPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition + new Vector3(0f,0f,distance));
            switch (shape)
            {
                case 0:
                    primitive = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    primitive = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    primitive = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cylinder);
                    break;
            }
        }
        primitive.transform.localScale = new Vector3(Random.Range(0.1f,1f)*size,Random.Range(0.1f,1f)*size,Random.Range(0.1f,1f)*size);
        primitive.transform.position = clickPosition;
        primitive.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Vector4(Random.Range(0f,red),Random.Range(0f,green),Random.Range(0f,blue),1f);
        primitive.transform.parent = this.transform;
        if(timeDestroy)
        {
            Destroy(primitive,3f);
        }
        mousePosition.text =  "Mouse Position x: " + Input.mousePosition.x.ToString("F0") + ", y: " + Input.mousePosition.y.ToString("F0");

    }
public void changeShape(int tempShape)

{
    shape.tempShape;
}
public void changeRed(float tempRed)
{
   red = tempRed;
}
public void ChangeGreen(float tempGreen)
{
    green = tempGreen;
}
public void ChangeBlue(float tempBlue)
{
    blue = tempBlue;
}
public void destroyObjects()
{
    foreach (Transform child in transform)
    {
        Destroy(child.gameObject);
    }
}
public void ToggleTimedDestroy(bool timer)
{
    timeDestroy = timer;
}
public void ChangeSize(float temp)
{
   size = temp;
}    
}
```

Comment: Maybe related to [this and similar known issues](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/events-generated-by-the-player-input-component-do-not-have-callbackcontext-set-as-their-parameter-type?_ga=2.200301357.2050606337.1607439873-1503811403.1600323997)? Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the Inspector on the event's name, [onValueChanged](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown-onValueChanged.html) wants an argument of type System.Int32.
If you change your method to `public void changeShape(System.Int32 shape)` you'll see it at the top of the list.